# Scroll instantly to the top when smooth is set with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage with the following set:

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

However, I have a case where I have to scroll to the top without any smoothing.
According to the Mozilla docs I could use the `behavior: 'auto'` option.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScrollToOptions/behavior

But it wouldn't be the web if it wasn't broken. When I use the following:

```
window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'auto' });
```

I still get an animated scroll.

How can I (easily) get instant scrolling?

Comment: Which browser you're trying? It's working for me in chrome.

Comment: @Prawinsoni also chrome, are you sure you did set the `scroll-behavior: smooth;` css property?

Comment: Okay after setting the CSS, it's not able to overwrite the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have set the *css* property `scroll-behavior` to smooth.

The `window.scrollTo` *behavior* option doens't override the *css* value.

---

Replace

```
window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'auto' });
```

With

```
document.documentElement.style = "scroll-behavior: auto";
document.documentElement.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'auto' }); // or just leave it window.scrollTo(...), doens't matter. I just like it this way ;)
```

```js
let button = document.getElementById("test");

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Reset the CSS scroll-behavior property
  document.documentElement.style = "scroll-behavior: auto";
  document.documentElement.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'auto' }); // or just leave it window.scrollTo(...), doens't matter
  
  // Do more stuff here, like setting the 'scroll-behavior' back to smooth .....
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100000px;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<button id="test">
Scroll down then click me
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this, it's not a 100% proper solution but the trick worked:

```js
document.querySelector('#gototop').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('html').classList.add('gototop');
  window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'auto'})
});

var isScrolling;
// Tracking scroll end to make the CSS in html as it was.
window.addEventListener('scroll', function ( event ) {

 window.clearTimeout( isScrolling );
 isScrolling = setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector('html').classList.remove('gototop');
 }, 66);
}, false);
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

html.gototop {
  scroll-behavior: auto;
}
```

```html
<br><div>he behavior property of the ScrollToOptions dictionary specifies whether the scrolling should animate smoothly,<br> or happen instantly in a single jump.
<br>
This is actually defined on the ScrollOptions dictionary, which is implemented by ScrollToOptions.
<br>
Syntax
behavior: ScrollBehavior
Value
An enum, the value of which can be one of the following:

smooth: The scrolling animates smoothly.
auto: The scrolling happens in a single jump.
Examples
In our scrolltooptions example (see it live)<br> we include a form that allows the user to enter three values — two numbers repr<br>esenting the left and top properties (i.e. the positions to scroll to alon<br>g the<br> X and Y axes), and a checkbox indicating <br>whether they want smooth scr<br>olling enabled or not.
<br>
When the form is submitted, an event handler is run that<br> puts the entered values into<br> a ScrollToOptions dictionary, and then invok<br>es the Window.ScrollTo() method, passing the dictionary as a parameter:<br>
<br>
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.<br>preventDefault();
  var scrollOptions = {
    left<br>: leftInput.value,
    top: topInput.value,
    behavior<br>: scrollInput.checked ? 'smooth' : 'auto'<br>
  }
<br>
  window.scrollTo(scrollOptions);<br>
});<br>
Specifications
Specification Status Comment<br>
CSS Object Model (CSSOM) View Mod<br>ule
The definition of 'behavior' in that <br>specification. Working Draft  
Browser compatibility
Update compatibility data on GitHub<br>
Desktop Mobile
Chrome Edge Firefox Internet Explorer<br> Opera Safari Android webview Chrome for Android Firefox for Android Opera for Android Safari on iOS Samsung Internet
behavior Full support45 No supportNo Ful<br>l supportYes No supportNo Full support3<br>2 No supportNo Full support45 Fu<br>ll support45 Full supportYes Full supp<br>ort32 No supportNo Full supportYes<br>

<br>
<br>


What are we missing?
Lege<br>nd
Full support <br>
Full support<br>
No support <br>
No support<br>
See also
ScrollTo<br>Options
<br>
Metadata
Last<br> modified: Mar 18, 2019, by MDN contributors
Related Topics
ScrollTo<br>Options
Properties<br>
behavior<br>
left
top
Learn the best of web development</div><br>
<button id="gototop" >Go to top</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use just *{top: 0}* object without any "behavior" key. Also take a note, 'behavour' property is not supported in Internet Eplorer, by default it will be instant scroll.

Comment: If you create a demo using his code and your solution, you can see this doens't solve the issue. Try to test the OP's code first before posting an answer.